# Java Swing 2D array of JTextField to take user input values

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jlabel

Hello I need to create a UI that required user to input array coll and row nrs and after this display this array with empty cells where user input values of array after this i chose a calculation method from a combox and press "Solve" button and based on selecte method make some caculation, can anybody help me with matrix creation please ?

Comment: You need to use `GridLayout` or `GridBagLayout` to display your components into a cell, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39234273/how-do-i-resize-jcomponents-in-gridlayout/39235219#39235219). That example uses `JButtons` but use `JTextFields` for your needs