# Why can't I add buttons to my GridLayout JPanel?

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to add 24 `JButtons` to the `GridLayout` of my `JPanel` `buttonPanel`, but when I run it, I see that no buttons are added. (At least, they are not visible!). I tried giving the `buttonPanel` a background color, and it
was visible.
Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

This is my code (there is an other class):

```
package com.Egg;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;



public class NormalCalc implements ActionListener {
    static JPanel normalCalcPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(6,4,10,10));
    Font font = new Font("Monospaced Bold", Font.BOLD, 18);
    
    JButton powB = new JButton("^");
    JButton sqrtB = new JButton("sqrt(");
    JButton hOpenB = new JButton("(");
    JButton hCloseB = new JButton(")");
    JButton delB = new JButton("DEL");
    JButton acB = new JButton("AC");
    JButton mulB = new JButton("*");
    JButton divB = new JButton("/");
    JButton addB = new JButton("+"); 
    JButton minB = new JButton("-");
    JButton decB = new JButton(".");
    JButton equB = new JButton("=");
    JButton negB = new JButton("(-)");
    
    JButton[] numberButtons = new JButton[10];
    JButton[] functionButtons = new JButton[13];

    
    
    public NormalCalc() {
        functionButtons[0] = powB;
        functionButtons[1] = delB;
        functionButtons[2] = acB;
        functionButtons[3] = sqrtB;
        functionButtons[4] = mulB;
        functionButtons[5] = divB;
        functionButtons[6] = hOpenB;
        functionButtons[7] = addB;
        functionButtons[8] = minB;
        functionButtons[9] = hCloseB;
        functionButtons[10] = decB;
        functionButtons[11] = negB;
        functionButtons[12] = equB;
        
        
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            numberButtons[i] = new JButton(String.valueOf(i));
            numberButtons[i].setFocusable(false);
            numberButtons[i].setFont(font);
            numberButtons[i].addActionListener(this);
        }
        for (int i=0; i <13; i++) {
            functionButtons[i].setFocusable(false);
            functionButtons[i].setFont(font);
            functionButtons[i].addActionListener(this);
        }
        normalCalcPanel.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 700);
        
        buttonPanel.setBounds(50, 200, 400, 400);
        

        // Adding the buttons;
        buttonPanel.add(functionButtons[0]);
        buttonPanel.add(numberButtons[7]);
        buttonPanel.add(numberButtons[8]);
        buttonPanel.add(numberButtons[9]);
        buttonPanel.add(functionButtons[1]);
        buttonPanel.add(functionButtons[2]);
        buttonPanel.add(functionButtons[3]);
        buttonPanel.add(numberButtons[4]);
        buttonPanel.add(numberButtons[5]);
        buttonPanel.add(numberButtons[6]);
        buttonPanel.add(functionButtons[4]);
        buttonPanel.add(functionButtons[5]);
        buttonPanel.add(functionButtons[6]);
        buttonPanel.add(numberButtons[1]);
        buttonPanel.add(numberButtons[2]);
        buttonPanel.add(numberButtons[3]);
        buttonPanel.add(functionButtons[7]);
        buttonPanel.add(functionButtons[8]);
        buttonPanel.add(functionButtons[9]);
        buttonPanel.add(numberButtons[0]);
        buttonPanel.add(functionButtons[10]);
        buttonPanel.add(functionButtons[11]);
        buttonPanel.add(functionButtons[12]);
        
        buttonPanel.repaint();
        
        normalCalcPanel.add(buttonPanel);
        normalCalcPanel.add(MainMath.exitButton);
        
        MainMath.frame.add(normalCalcPanel);
        MainMath.frame.repaint();
    }



    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        
        
    }
}
```

Other (main) class:

```
package com.Egg;

import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class MainMath implements ActionListener {

    static JFrame frame = new JFrame("Math Tools");
    static JButton exitButton = new JButton("Exit");

    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    JLabel mainLabel = new JLabel("Select your tool.", SwingConstants.CENTER);


    JButton nB = new JButton("Normal Calc.");
    JButton tB = new JButton("Right Triangle Calc.");
    JButton eB = new JButton("Equations Calc.");



public MainMath() { 
    frame.setBounds(300, 300, 500, 700);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(null);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    
    mainPanel.setLayout(null);
    mainPanel.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 700);
    
    mainLabel.setBounds(100, 25, 300, 50);
    mainLabel.setFont(new Font("Monospaced Bold", Font.BOLD, 18));
    
    nB.setBounds(100, 100, 300, 40);
    tB.setBounds(100, 150, 300, 40);
    eB.setBounds(100, 200, 300, 40);
    nB.setFocusable(false);
    tB.setFocusable(false);
    eB.setFocusable(false);
    nB.addActionListener(this);
    tB.addActionListener(this);
    eB.addActionListener(this);
    
    mainPanel.add(mainLabel);
    mainPanel.add(nB);
    mainPanel.add(tB);
    mainPanel.add(eB);
    frame.add(mainPanel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    
    exitButton.setBounds(16, 10, 80, 35);
    exitButton.setFocusable(false);
    exitButton.addActionListener(this);
    
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new MainMath();
    
    System.out.println("");
    
}

public void setMainScreen() {
    frame.remove(exitButton);
    
    frame.remove(NormalCalc.normalCalcPanel);
    frame.add(mainPanel);
    frame.repaint();
}

public static JFrame getFrame() {
    return frame;
}





@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == exitButton) 
        setMainScreen();
    
    if (e.getSource() == nB) {
        frame.remove(mainPanel);
        new NormalCalc();
    }
    if (e.getSource() == tB)
        new TriangleCalc();
    if (e.getSource() == eB)
        new EquationCalc();
}

}
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to add components to your frame **after** displaying it?  If that is the case, remember to [revalidate](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JComponent.html#revalidate()) it.

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong I set the panel in another panel which I then set in the frame, after I add the buttons :).

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Also, your panel should not be static. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33739623/how-to-add-a-shortcut-key-for-a-jbutton-in-java/33739732#33739732 for a simple example that will show you how to better structure your code so all the components are added to the panel before the frame is made visible. The class posted here should NOT be referencing the frame. The frame should be created in the main() method and then you add child panels to the frame.

Comment: If you're trying to add / remove panels, use a [`CardLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Answer (score 1):

I see multiple issues in your code:

1. Your arrangement of your buttons is weird looking at first glance.
2. `normalCalcPanel` is `static`, why? It should never be
3. `setBounds(...)` when using layout managers, those statements are ignored, so no need for them
4. `repaint()` unless you've added / removed any element AFTER you've displayed your GUI, these calls are unnecessary, and should come with `revalidate()` as well.
5. `MainMath.exitButton` another `static` component, STOP
6. `MainMath.frame.add(normalCalcPanel)` implies that your `JFrame` called `frame` is `static` as well, which again, shouldn't be

And (I'm gonna guess here) more than probably you're creating a second instance inside `MainMath`, but because we don't have the code from that class we don't know what's going on

I ran your code and it looks ok, so that's why I believe your `MainMath` is creating another instance of `JFrame`

[image]

Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39235219/2180785) of a calculator arrangement, that should help you to structure your code similarly, not the GUI but the components and classes

---

#### Edit

> Okay, I understand now that I should not use static things, but how can I add a panel to a frame which I created in another class? I used 'static', because it seemed to work

Let's make an analogy for this case, imagine that your `JFrame` is a book, and that your `JPanel`s are the sheets of that book, when you write on those sheets, you don't add / paste the book to the sheets, you add the sheets to the book.

So, in this case it's the same, your main class should create the `JPanels` and add those to your `JFrame`, your `JPanel` classes shouldn't have knowledge of your `JFrame`

In the case of the book, your sheets don't need to know to which book the belong, you know that and the book knows which sheets belong to it, not viceversa.

I made an example to show you what I mean by this, I didn't recreate your GUI but made it as simple as I could for you to get the idea:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class AnotherCalculator {
    private JFrame frame;
    private CalculatorPanel calculatorPanel;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new AnotherCalculator()::createAndShowGUI);
    }
    
    private void createAndShowGUI() {
        frame = new JFrame(getClass().getSimpleName());
        calculatorPanel = new CalculatorPanel();
        
        frame.add(calculatorPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class CalculatorPanel extends JPanel {
    private String[] operations = {"+", "-", "*", "/", "DEL", "AC", "(", ")", "-", "^", "SQRT", ".", "+/-", "="};
    private static final int NUMBER_OF_DIGITS = 10;
    
    private JButton[] buttons;
    
    public CalculatorPanel() {
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 4, 5, 5));
        
        buttons = new JButton[operations.length + NUMBER_OF_DIGITS];
        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            if (i < NUMBER_OF_DIGITS) {
                buttons[i] = new JButton(String.valueOf(i));
            } else {
                buttons[i] = new JButton(operations[i - NUMBER_OF_DIGITS]);
            }
            this.add(buttons[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
1. Ye, I couldn't test it because of the problem.
2. I want to remove the panel from the frames in other classes. The only solution to do this (I thought) is to make it static.
I'll add the code of the other class too :)

Comment: We don't want the code from the other classes, we want a [mre]

Comment: Okay, I understand now that I should not use static things, but how can I add a panel to a frame which I created in another class? I used 'static', because it seemed to work :).